# How to export nodejs eventemitter

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm having some serious troubles trying to export / use eventemitter across multiple modules.  Essentially I'm looking to place all my listeners and invoked functions in one module called EventListen.js.  Next, for example my Order.js model where I after a user is saved I want the function in EventListen.js to hear the event.  I've read through some tutorials and tried to do this a few different ways but not having much luck...

```
/**** EventListen.js ****/

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

myeventmodule.on('newuser', function (user) {

  console.log(user);

});
module.exports = myeventemitter;





/**** User.js or EventPublisher.js ****/
var myeventemitter = require('Eventlisten');

schema.post('save', function (user) {

  myeventmodule.emit('newuser', user);

})
```

Comment: Is `socket` the same object as `myeventmodule`?  A more complete (non)working example would help.

Comment: added some more to make it a bit more complete.. And I'm sorry no they are not, I simply pasted that from a socket event I had in my project.  I literally am just trying to emit events from different modules, and have the the EventLister be able to here the emits..

Answer (score 2):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

module.exports = new EventEmitter();

exports.emitSomethingLater = function()
 setTimeout(function() {
  module.exports.emit('something');
 }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.